# How to give sudo privileges to some user

Tags: linux

I want to give an user sudo privileges to execute a script. In other words the user should be able to run the command without using sudo.

I tried to edit the sudoers file in the /etc directory using visudo but it was of no use

Comment: You have a good question, but you have posted to the wrong StackEachange site. I’m voting to close this question because your question is not "Programming" related, it is more appropriate for the StackExchange site [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). That said, the answers here should have already answered your question. Note, some distros use the `wheel` group instead of `sudo` for sudo privileges.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To give sudo privileges to a user on a Linux system, you need to add the user to the sudo group. You can do this using the usermod command. Here's an example:

```
sudo usermod -aG sudo username
```

Editing the sudoers file directly with a text editor, especially one like visudo, is the correct approach, but it must be done with caution. The visudo command opens the sudoers file in a safe way, and it checks for syntax errors before saving changes. If there's an error in the sudoers file, it could potentially lock you out of sudo access, so using visudo is strongly recommended.

Here's the correct way to use visudo to edit the sudoers file:

Open the sudoers file using visudo:

```
sudo visudo
```

Navigate to the section that looks like this:

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Below the root entry, add the following line to grant sudo privileges to a specific user:

```
username   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Save and exit the editor and If you are using visudo, it will perform syntax checking before saving.

Hope it helps!

Comment: You do NOT want to use any text-editor, but instead want to use `visudo` *exclusively* to modify the `sudoers` file. (I think that is what you meant given the additional format checking you discuss in your answer) Note, many distributions do not have a `sudo` group, the `wheel` group has traditionally been used. Also note, this question is quasi off-topic on StackOverflow (not programming related) and should be migrated to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). This is a "*How do I use/do xyz in Linux*" question.

Comment: Please don't answer questions not related to SO! This is a programming question Q&A site.

Answer (score -2):

Your question kind of doesn't make sense. A script can be thought of an executable. When an executable is executed, it is executed as a specific user.
Eg.

```bash
$ whoami
billy
```

Here, `whoami` prints the username of the user who called it. Now, `billy` can **only** do things he is authorized to do, like modifying his own files, calling executables, etc. The user `billy` is not authorized to do tasks like modifying system files or restarting system services. But sometimes, we need to do those tasks and we (as a person) have authorization do so. Instead of logging in as root (which is somewhat tedious), we use `sudo`. When you prefix a command with `sudo`, it is executed as the `root` user. Eg.

```bash
$ sudo whoami
root
```

Notice, eventhough `sudo whoami` is executed by `billy`, `whoami` says it is called by `root`.

Now, `/etc/sudoers` file specifies who is allowed to use the `sudo` command. Use `visudo` to edit it. To allow billy to use `sudo`, the following line can be added to `/etc/sudoers`

```
billy ALL=(ALL:ALL)
```

Now, if you want to execute a script as `root` but you don't want to use `sudo`, you can log in as `root` and run the script.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Biffen. Should have cross checked my answer once before posting! The error is fixed now.